solution-verification | find a and then compare it to b
the problem
a) Find the real numbers $x,y$ for which the number $a$ has the minimum value, where $a=\sqrt{4x^2+y^2-12x-4y+25}$
b)compare number $b=\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}}$ with the minimum value of $a$
my solution
a) First of all I wrote $a=\sqrt{4x^2+y^2-12x-4y+25}=\sqrt{(2x-3)^2+(y-2)^2+12}$ and because the perfect square is always positive, then $a\leq \sqrt{12}$, which make $a$ minimum value be $\sqrt{12}$, and this occurs when $x=\frac{3}{2}$ and $y=2$
b) we have to compare $\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}} ... \sqrt{12}$ I squared everything up
$13+4\sqrt{3}  ...   12$ then I decreased by 12
$1+4\sqrt{3} >0$
so, $b>a$
As you can see i put this at solution-verification. I'm not sure if my statement that $a\leq \sqrt{12}$ is right and this case occurs when both values have $0$. I fell like i need to justify more but i don't know how.
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Some symbols seem to not work. Can you edit your question so that it can be understood by the community ?

@Kolakoski54 Actually i put that square to show that we are comparing two values... Sorry for the misunderstand...

I don't think your readers will understand that notation, I suggest changing it.  And what does $\sqrt {12}|()^2$ mean?   Or $12|-12$?

OK I now understand the notation "|" that seems to mean that you apply the operation that follows. It is not really easy to read. You could edit your question explaining your work with words, it is sometimes better than poorly chosen notations. Thank you in advance !

@lulu Look at my edit

Yes, that's clear now.  But, $a$ is a defined quantity, set to be the minimum of that radical expression.  Your argument showing $a=\sqrt {12}$ is clear and correct.  See WA for verification.

To be clear, there is no "$a≤\sqrt {12}$".  That doesn't make sense.  $a$ is a precisely defined real number which, as you correctly demonstrate, is $\sqrt {12}$.

@lulu oooo...ok...i understand what you are saying...i think it would better to say that $(2x−3)^2+(y−2)^2+12 \leq 12$. Thank you for your help... also point b is correct?

You mean $≥12$.

$b$ is clearly greater than $a$.  After all, $b^2>13$ while $a^2=12$.

First, it seems your inequality symbols are the wrong way around: you mean to say that because $(2x-3)^2\geq 0$ and $(y-2)^2\geq 0$, that $a\geq \sqrt{12}$, whereas you have written $a\leq \sqrt{12}$.
I agree with your argument for a), and your solution of $x = \frac 32$, $y=2$. If you are familiar with them (otherwise don't worry about it), we can double check this answer by using derivatives to find extrema (and checking that such an extremum is a minimum as required). Using derivatives would also be applicable in more general situations of having to find extrema, whereas your solution is quicker in this specific case.
I also agree with what you found for b). You have the right strategy here, though there is one subtlety which you do not mention and I would like to give you some advice on notation, if that's ok.
First of all, note that $a = \sqrt{4x^2 + y^2-12x-4y+25}$, so we cannot just compare it to $b$. What you are comparing to $b$ is the minimum value which $a$ takes, which we could call $a_{min}$, for example.
Second, you have the right idea: we wish to compare $a_{min}^2$ and $b^2$ by considering their difference. But why not just write this? For example, you could say:

Consider $b^2 - a_{min}^2$. We find
\begin{align}
b^2 - a_{min}^2 = 13 + 4\sqrt 3 - 12 = 1+4\sqrt 3 > 0
\end{align}
We conclude $a_{min}^2 < b^2$.

Now we come to the subtlety I was talking about: Every square root has two solutions. For example, if we know $x^2>4$, we know that either $x>2$ or $x<-2$. In other words: $|x| > 2$. The same principle holds here: either $b>|a_{min}|$ or $b < -|a_{min}|$. (We need to take the absolute value of $a_{min}$ here to ensure we get the correct intervals. Using the same example as before, we could write $x^2>(-2)^2 = 4$ and you see we have to take the absolute value.) We thus conclude $|a_{min}|<|b|$. But now we can use that both $a_{min}$ and $b$ are positive to conclude $a_{min}<b$.
